# vim do not fold everything on first fold

Tags: vim

When I close the first fold in a buffer (`zc` in normal mode), all the folds are automatically closed. Is there a way to just close the given fold without closing the rest?

I have `foldmethod=syntax`. Observed with python but probably this applies to other languages.

Example python file

[image]

`zc` on method a()

[image]

As you can see, all methods: `a`, `b`, `c` are folded. Desired behaviour is for only method `a` to be folded, as shown below:

[image]

This only happens on the first time a fold is closed in a buffer. After re-opening all the folds, `zc` will only close the proper fold.

EDIT: I believe this has to do with `SimpylFold` plugin. I have set `nofoldenable` by default. When I `zc`, it looks like `SimpylFold` sets `foldenable`, which automatically folds all the methods.

Comment: Can you give us a bit of example code so we can recreate this exactly as you are describing it?  As it stands your description can be interpreted in a couple of ways.

Comment: @RandyMorris added screenshots to question

Comment: This does indeed seem inappropriate. I'll take a look tomorrow if no one has answered yet. Unfortunately I can't test until then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause was a weird interaction with `nofoldenable` and the plugin SimpylFold. I set `nofoldenable` by default. If you have `foldenable`, unless you add additional commands all your folds are closed by default.

Now when using the SimpylFold plugin, `zc` on first use also sets `foldenable`, which will close all folds.

The solution is to add something like this to your `~/.vimrc`

```
autocmd FileType python setlocal foldenable foldlevel=20
```

This enables folding locally for python files while leaving the folds open on buffer open. Then `zc` behaves normally.